# Is there something that studies equivalent forms of writing and expression?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Supose we have: $x^2+x$, one could write it as $x(x+1)$ which would be equivalent to the first expression. I guess there might be a finite number of ways of writing expressions such that they are equivalent.

Is there a field of study that studies arbitrary ways to express the same formula?

Comment: I don't think those are equal.

Comment: Small typo. $x^2 + x = x(x+1)$, or then $x^2 + 1 = (x+i)(x-i)$.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are expressions, then the assertion that $A=B$ is often called an *identity*. There are a number of fields in which identities play an important role.

Comment: There's clearly not a finite number of polybnomial expressions for $x^2 + 1$ as you stipulated no "form" and you could simply $\pm$ anything you want.  On the other hand if you try restricting yourself to *not* allow $\pm$ of other expressions, then you won't be able to search for the "optimal" expression (one that when computed directly as the parentheses say, results in the smallest number of calculator ops), as some things can be reduced only when things are $\pm$'d in, in the sense that if you completely expanded the expression into a sum of monomials, then there's redundancy, can't win...

Comment: @JHance Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely a part of CA - [computer algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra).